# Getting keydown event parent element, jQuery

Tags: jquery, keydown

I am trying to identify the immediate parent (paragraph element) of the cursor within a contenteditable div which looks like this:

```
<div id=base>
<div ce='1'  contenteditable='true'>
<p id='unique'>Paragraph one</p>
<p>Paragraph two</p>
</div>
</div>
```

If I bind a .click event to the 'ce' div, then event.currentTarget is reported as the paragraph in which the click occurs. But to track the cursor I need to use the .keydown event

```
$('#base').on({ 
    keydown: function(event) {
        myLog(' nodeName: '+event.currentTarget.nodeName);
    },
// With the following selector the event is triggered with the cursor 
// anywhere in 'ce', and .currentTarget is the 'ce' div.
}, '[ce]');
// With this selector the event is never triggered regardless of cursor position
}, '#unique');
```

Why is the event not being triggered, and how can I achieve my aim?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can get the element from your event object as the event is fired on #base and so #base is the target (and not the textnode or paragraph).

You could use the current selection to get the container (textnode) that contains the cursor at the moment when the event occurs and use that container to search for the paragraph.

This could look like this:

```
$('#base').on({ 
  keydown: function(event) {
    // get current selection
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    if (selection.rangeCount === 1) {
      // get container of cursor
      var textnode = selection.getRangeAt(0).startContainer;

      // use jquery to get paragraph
      console.log($(textnode).parents('p'));
    }
  }
});
```

This is just a very simple (not cross-browser) example (tested in FireFox). For the real code you would have to do some more checks to get the current cursor position. To make your life easier you could have a look at rangy:

https://code.google.com/p/rangy/

This is a library that handles selections.